# Same problem watching downloaded video files but not online videos

Tags: 16.04, video, vlc

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell Latitude E6330 notebook. Everything works just fine, except when I try to watch some video files I downloaded. So I installed VLC, SMP and mpv. Then I installed a codec. I updated. I restarted. Same problem: whichever video player I use, of the ones I mentioned above, to open a video file, the video gets interrupted every few seconds and so on. Why do I have the same problem with watching downloaded video files, regardless of the media program I use, but I don't have this problem when watching online videos? I watch videos for hours on youtube but I never experienced this or any other problem. Can all the video files I downloaded be corrupt? They didn't come from the same place. Should I try to use a program to fix the corrupt files (if they really are corrupt - I didn't get any notification of the files being corrupt)? Or is the problem deeper than that? I am aware that my laptop is pretty old and the version of Ubuntu I used is also not the newest out there, but it's the best I can do for now. Please help. I am out of ideas.

Comment: The last solution in this link might help, if it doesn't just enable again. askubuntu.com/questions/762083/…

Answer (score 0):

At this point I am not sure where to say and start if the issue is with playback on all of the media player.  But maybe you can narrow it down if you have an other computer you can use by putting a video on a usb or cd from your computer that is not working and play it on a different computer or dvd player.  If they are playing just fine there, then you will be sure that downloading is not the issue, but if they are playing with the same issue, then you will be sure it is something corrupting the downloads.  At the same time, if you have a dvd slot in your machine you can try putting in a dvd and see if it plays okay on your computer using vlc.  Just a way to help narrow down the problem. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) Unfortunatelly, I tried watching .VOB files from an original DVD (so I know those files are not corrupt) in VLC, and then I got an error about the MRL. So I installed browser-plugin-vlc in terminal. I get the same error. Is my laptop so old that I can't watch anything on it or is it another problem? Please help.